# Strong solution to parabolic equation without differentiability assumption on coefficient?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Consider on $(0,T)\times \Omega$, $\Omega$ a bounded domain
$$u_t(t,x) - a(u(t,x))\Delta u(t,x) = f(t,x)$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$$
where $a$ is real-valued and satisfies 
$C_1 \leq a(r) \leq C_2$ for all $r$ where both constants are strictly positive. Assume $f$ is as smooth as needed.

We know that $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ with $u_t \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

Is it also true that $u_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2) = L^2(Q)$ (and thus also $\Delta u \in L^2(Q)$)?

I was under the impression that this is true only when one knows something about the differentiability of $t \mapsto a(u(t,x))$. However, I am informed this is not necessary an assumption. Could someone sketch a proof or refer me to a source? Thanks.

Comment: What conditions do you put on your initial data ? If you allow Dirac measures, your conclusion does not hold.

Comment: @Hachino Definitely more smooth than that, let's say $u_0 \in H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: There is a rather extensive literature on parabolic equations with nonsmooth coefficients. The work of Ladyzhenskaya and Uraltseva is a good place to start searching.